# When exporting a class to a static lib in C++, how could I conceal the private function of the class?

Tags: c++, oop, static-libraries

EG,

```
//this is myclass.h
class myclass
{
public:
  int publicfunction();
private:  
  int myprivatefunction();
};

//myclass.cpp

#include "myclass.h"
int myclass::publicfunction()
{myprivatefunction();
blabla...}

int myclass::privatefunction()
{blabla...}
```

So, for users can access the class,we will provide the header file to the users. But shouldn't we conceal the internal implement details of the class??? I mean, when the users get `myclass.h`, they will find that the class contains a private function `myprivatefunction`

Comment: What's the big deal, considering that they are unable to call these functions?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight shouldn't the users could only access those functions they are able to call?

Comment: Define what it means to access a function. How a user can access one he's not able to call?

Comment: @n.m. The user might try `#define private public #include <myclass.h>`

Comment: @n.m. well when speaking of "access" I mean "get the definiton/declaration of a function".

Comment: You mean *see* it, not *do* something with it. By this logic we should spray-paint all windows black, for fear of random people looking through them. "Private" in C++ doesn't mean it's secret, it means random people cannot touch it.

Comment: If you want a secret implementation, don't put it in a public header. There are ways of separating an interface from an implementation, including opaque pointers (look up PIMPL) and abstract base classes.

Comment: @n.m. thanks a lot:-) .this may be my misunderstanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header file isn't just your public interface. It's a description of your data layout for the compiler. It is perfectly normal that the private members get shown in the header file. `private` is *not* a security mechanism and never will be.

It's a bit strange, but it falls out from a simple yet efficient way of going about the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can export the private members inside a `struct`

```
//this is myclass.h
class myclass{
private:
   struct myClassPrivateMembers;
   myClassPrivateMembers* privParts;
public:
   // ...
};
```

And in the *.cpp file:

```
//this is myclass.cpp
struct *myClassPrivateMembers{
   int myprivatefunction();
}

myclass::myclass(){
   privParts = new myClassPrivateMembers;
};
```

That way the user won't be able to see things you hidden inside `myClassPrivateMembers`, because they'll be inside the *.cpp file, not declared in the header file.

This is widelly known as the ["pimpl" idiom](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom).

Comment: This is very useful when you want to provide an implementation that is binary-compatible against versions. It's mostly silly just to hide what your private members are.

Comment: Mostly, but not always. Sometimes giving the user a description of the private members is a really bad idea - like when your doing some sort of library that encodes/decodes data. But in most cases - I gotta agree with that statement.

Comment: Can you explain your example?

Comment: If you're designing a library used to encode data, you may want to store some sort of seed inside your private members. In that case - you really don't want the user to have the information about where the seed is located, so you hide the privade members inside a dedicted `struct`. People will still be able to hack inside that, but it's gonna be a bit harder to locate the `struct` data inside the `exe`

Comment: You're seeking a false sense of security. pimpl is *not* a security mechanism!!

Comment: It's _not_. But it can be used to strenghten the security you _already_ have. I never said "use pimpl as your primal security mechanism". I've said "it's sometimes a bad idea to show the private members". Please note the difference and don't put words inside my mouth :)

Comment: You aren't strengthening your security in the example. Your adding obscurity, and in a pretty poor way. This only provides false security.

Comment: Obscurity and ambiguity are security when it comes to reverse engineering. Maybe you never had the need to protect your code against those kind of things, but that's not a matter of a single statement with a "yes" or "no" in it. I also don't see the need to explain myself - the user got what he wanted, and all people are happy. Including me. It's his choice why and when he will use it.

Answer (score 0):

You might as well separate your interface and your implementation.

myinterface.h

```
class myinterface
{
public:
  virtual int publicfunction() = 0;
};
```

myclass.h

```
class myclass : public myinterface
{
public:
  virtual int publicfunction();
private:
  int privatefunction();
};
```

myclass.cpp

```
#include "myclass.h"
int myclass::publicfunction()
{myprivatefunction();
blabla...}

int myclass::privatefunction()
{blabla...}
```

You don't have to expose myclass.{h,cpp} to library users.

But this might be an overkill... (I would call this "Java folks' way")